# Selenium WebDriver using Java in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

How to find the Xpath or id of an Element in IE for accessing it in Selenium WebDriver. I have used "Fire Bug" to get the same in Firefox and Chrome. It is working fine for Firefox and Chrome but not working in IE. Please someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE doesn't have this feature built in, but once you know the ID or xpath you can then apply it to IE.  Using Firefox or Chrome, right click on the element, select "Inspect Element"

Answer (score 0):

As @user2272115 has suggested, **there's no inbuilt feature like "Firepath"**(i.e, plugin of firebug tool for inspecting and fetching xpath/css of element(s)) **in IE**. 
Furthermore, **the xpath/id of an element doesn't change with respect to browsers**. Hence, you can use the same xpath/id of the element to take further action in IE too. :)